# Swipe from left to return to previous screen in iOS flutter webview app

Tags: ios, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

In iOS, if we swipe from left towards center of screen, we can switch back to previous screen. I want to have similar functionality in the flutter web view app. How can I do that??

Comment: You can use [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) and call `Navigator.pop(context)` to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: Can you please share your answer?